# Proving Odd & Even Functions

Tags: functions, education

For the following:

> If $f$ is an odd function, then $|f|$ is _______.
>
> If $f$ is an odd function and $g$ is an even function then, $(f\circ g)(x)$ is _______.
>
> If $f$ is an odd function and $g$ is an odd function, then $(f\cdot g)(x)$ is _______.

I can't tell the answer all of a sudden, however whenever I start trying to prove them, I get it.

Anyways, how would you guys approach this? I learned how to actually go about proving it but is there anyway you can solve this without actually trying to prove it?

Comment: by definition of odd function f(-x)=-f(x),|f(-x)|=|-f(x)|=|f(x)| so it is even function.second one,if g(-x)=g(x) even,and f(x)odd then f(g(-x))=-f(g(x)) is odd,third one,g(-x)=-g(x) and f(-x)=-f(x) then f(-x)*g(-x)=(-f(x))*(-g(x))=f(x)g(x) even

Comment: Whenever I try to decide if a function $f$ is odd, even, or neither, the sensible thing to do is simplify $f(-x)$. If you get $-f(x)$, it's odd. If you get $f(x)$, it's even. If you can't easily get one or the other, then it's probably neither, but to be certain, choose some specific values of $x$ (e.g. $x = \pm1, \pm2, \pm3$ etc) and find one such that $f(-x) \neq \pm f(x)$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Be aware if $f(-x)=-f(x)$ then $f$ is not even but on the contrary odd. :)

Comment: @Tolaso: Good point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** If $f$ is odd , then $|f|$ is even because $\left | f(-x) \right |= \left | -f(x) \right |= \left | f(x) \right |$.

**2.** If $f$ is odd and $g$ is even then $f\circ g$ is even. That is because if $h(x)=(f\circ g)(x)$ then:

$$h(-x)=\left ( f\circ g \right )(-x)= f\left ( g(-x) \right )= f(g(x))=h(x)$$

**3.** If $f$ is odd and $g$ is odd then $\varphi(x)=f(x) \cdot g(x)$ is even. That is because:

$$\varphi(-x)= f(-x) g(-x)= -f(x)\cdot (-g(x))= f(x)g(x)=\varphi(x)$$

*Fixed typos!*

Comment: Yes, I can do all of that but how did you learn this, did you know this and then go onto prove it or you had to prove it to learn it?

Comment: No. You use the definition of the odd and even function.

a) A function $f$ is odd if it is defined on a symmetric interval around zero , that is $[-a, a]$ and $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

b) A function $g$ is even if it is defined on a symmetric interval around zero , that is $[-a, a]$ and $f(-x)=f(x)$.

Now, consider the functions you want to study whether they are even or odd as new functions and use the definition.

Comment: Actually I considered it like that, I had no way of figuring them out until I started proving it. My professor on the other hand knows it and then goes on to prove it.

Comment: Hmm.. well at first you know nothing at mathematics till you prove it. Of course intuition is a guide but it is not proof. Your professor on the other hand is familiar with the subject he is teaching, therefore he knows the answers by heart. So he first tells you the answer and then proves it. 


But the right thing to do in maths in order to solve a math problem is to get a paper and a pencil.

Comment: @Asker123 consider marking the question as solved in the *check button*